# How can I get gulp to pause while a folder is unavailable?

Tags: vue.js, gulp, vue-cli, gulp-watch

I'm using gulp to watch for changes in several folders and sync them to a set of destinations. But during the build process, one of my source folders ("dist") is deleted and re-created, and this breaks `gulp.watch`, so I have to break and restart the process.

I was able to avoid the error by adding this to the top of my task:

```
gulp.task("home", function() {
    // Added this code
    var fs = require("fs")
    if (!fs.existsSync(sourceFolder)) {
        console.log("Dist folder temporarily unavailable, probably building...")
        return gulp
    }
    // Original task
    return gulp
        .src(sourceFolder)
        .pipe(changed(destFolder))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destFolder))
})

...

gulp.task("watch", function() {
    gulp.watch(sourceFolder, { interval: 500 }, gulp.series(["home"]))
})
```

But now, once the build process is complete and the dist folder comes back, *the task isn't firing again*, so the new files aren't being copied to the destination. I'm not getting any other errors.

Any ideas? Best I can figure is that perhaps `gulp.watch` is caching a handle to `sourceFolder`, so deleting and recreating the folder makes it lose track of the folder and thus it doesn't see the new folder and files.

Comment: Do you need to delete `dist`? Can your build task not leave `dist` alone and only remove the files within it?

Comment: Some more info about what is going on during "build" would be useful.

Comment: I'm building a web app using the VueJS CLI, it does a clean build into a `dist` folder by removing and replacing the folder. I have two tasks set up, one watching files in that folder and performing one action, and another task (both similar to the above code) watching a subfolder of `dist`. But a clean build is what I want -- I don't want old artifacts sitting in there and continuing to be synchronized to my destination folders.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having a similar problem earlier in the morning, and I think you have two options

**Option 1**

Instead of using gulp.watch, use [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch). If I recall correctly, gulp.watch doesn't watch for new added files, while gulp-watch does.

Then, use [gulp-plumber](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-plumber) to prevent stops on errors (like when your dist folder is missing)

**Option 2**

Upgrade to the [latest gulp version](https://gulpjs.com/). Things change a little bit, but they're definitely cleaner. In there the gulp's watch method doesn't have the problems described above and you won't need plumber since it won't stop the execution of the program after an error.

This is what I did earlier in the morning and was really simple. I guess it will depend on how big your gulpfile is and the time you have.

--

Hope this helps

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry @Jair-reina, I've already been using the latest version of gulp (4.0.2 currently), and the watch method definitely still exhibits this issue. I was able to suppress the error message for the src() function using the allowEmpty option, but the watch function simply stops watching when a folder along the glob path has been deleted. I finally gave up and found a hidden option in the build tool to *not* delete the dist folder, but this is suboptimal, as it leaves my distribution folder with artifacts from previous builds (filenames in the build include hashes to work around browser caching).